# Equivalence of Java static property in Go

Tags: java, go, static

```
class Array {
    public static int MAX_SIZE = 42;
}
Array arr = new Array();
int size = Array.MAX_SIZE;
```

So, we can create an object of class `Array`, and we also have a property of class `Array`. What will be the equivalence of this code in Go?

Comment: There isn't an equivalent in Go.

Comment: Are you asking about constants, or class variables?

Comment: @cricket_007 about class variables

Comment: Implementing equivalents of esoteric language features is rarely useful by itself. This seems like an XY problem. What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 2):

Go has no classes. Go has no static variables.  So there is no equivalent.

The closest concepts Go has are package constants, and struct fields.  Neither is exactly the same as what you're looking for.

Comment: I can have a struct and a package with same name?

Comment: You can, kind of by accident, but it's not useful. [Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) should always lowercase. A struct can have a lowercase name, too, but then its not exported, limiting its usefulness.  But there's no reason you'd ever need both to share a name anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Axel: "I can have a struct and a package with same name? " Yes, and it can be useful. For example, `package file; type file struct{ fd uintptr }; type File struct{ file *file }; func New() *File { return &File{file: new(file)} };`.

Comment: @peterSO: The similarity in names in that instance doesn't buy any utility that I see. May as well be `type foo` and you'd get the same functionality.

Comment: @Flimzy: "doesn't buy any utility that I see." That's OK. My comment was addressed to Axel.

Comment: @peterSO: Fair enough; My interpretation of Axel's question, in the larger context, was that he assumed the relationship between names added some value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plain equivalent:

```
package array

type Array struct {}

const MaxSize int = 42
```

In another place:

```
package main

import "./array"

fmt.Println(array.MaxSize)
```